# Poisson distribution problem including cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**The Question**

> The number of cracks in a section of highway that is significant
> enough to require repair is assumed to follow a Poisson distribution.
>
> (a) Let $Y$ be the number of cracks in $4$km, sketch the (CDF) Cumulative
> Distribution Function and graph up to $ = 4.5$.
>
> (b) If we should order the material to fix the cracks beforehand, how
> many packages of the material (One package for one crack) shall we
> order to ensure that all the cracks in $4$km can be fixed with at least
> $95\%$ chance?

**My Understanding**

For part (a), I tried to compute the probabilities of $Y=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ respectively, by using the formula of $Pr(X=k)=\frac{e^{-}\mu^k}{k!}$ however, when I tried to sum these probabilities together , $F(Y)$ turns out to exceed $1$, where probability should not $\gt 1$, what's wrong with that? What is the appropriate way to find the probabilities and thus I can graph up to $y=4.5$?

For part (b), for my understanding, this Poisson distribution has infinite number of cracks, so I am quite doubt that how to ensure that all the cracks in $4$km can be fixed with at least $95\%$ chance?

Comment: What value for $\mu$ have you used? There is not enough information to evaluate  the value of $\mu$

Comment: I used 2 @callculus

Comment: From where did you extract this information?

Comment: I used 2 As there is a part about Let  be the number of cracks in 10km and I have found that the expected value is 5, so I times 0.4 to get the expected value of 2 for this 4km question @callculus

Comment: the part I didn't showed above is  Let  be the number
of cracks in 10km, and we have the information that the probability of 4 cracks in 10km is
equal to the probability of 5 cracks in 10km (Pr( = 4) = Pr( = 5))
(a)  Please find the Expect value  (The expect cracks in 10km) and the
Variance of .
(b) Find the number of cracks in 10km which have the largest probability.
(c)  What’s the probability that at least one crack requires repair in 4km of the
highway? @callculus

Comment: As I have already solved that part, I forget to include this information above sorry

Comment: You seem to have mixed up use of `{ }` and `( )` in formatting math. I edited your formula for $P(X = k)$ so that it reads correctly. Please check that I did not change your meaning.

Comment: @user890391 OK. But the sum does not exceed 1: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-2}\cdot 2^k/k!=1$, especially not the first 6 summands.You can see it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E5+e%5E%28-2%29*2%5Ek%2Fk%21) as well.

Comment: Pr(Y=0) = {e^-2} =0.13533528323

Comment: @user890391 That´s true. Formatting tip: Put the $\LaTeX$-brackets around your terms: $\$\ldots\$$

Comment: I calculated like this, what's the problem with it? Pr(Y=0) = {e^-2} =0.13533528323.  Pr(Y=1)= \frac{(e^-2)(2)}{1!}=0.27067.  Pr(Y=2)= \frac{(e^-2)(2^2)}{2!}=0.27067.   Pr(Y=3)=  \frac{(e^-2)(2^3)}{3!}= 0.180447.   Pr(Y=4)=  \frac{(e^-2)(2^4)}{4!}= 0.09022.  Pr(Y=5)=  \frac{(e^-2)(2^5)}{5!}=0.036089

Comment: ohhh that's right it didn't exceed 1 maybe I have some calculation before

Comment: @user890391 That´s it. Your sum is 98.34%, like at the link I´ve posted.

Comment: how about part b, I have doubt about it as shown above, what's the way to solve it?@callculus

Comment: @user890391 I´ve posted a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** for part b: You have to set up the following inequality:

$$P(X\leq x)=\sum_{k=0}^x e^{-2}\cdot \frac{2^k}{k!}\geq 0.95,$$

where $X\sim Poi(2)$

From one of the previous exercises you know that $P(X\leq 5)>0.95$. So go on and try $x=4,3,...$ until $P(X\leq x)<0.95$.

Comment: (+1) If $\mu=2,$ then the relevant R code is `ppois(5, 2)`, which returns
$0.9834364.$ Also, `qpois(.95, 2)` which returns $5.$ So you shouldn't need "$x = 6, 7, \dots.$"

Comment: Good observation. I´ve changed my answer.

Comment: ohhh when x = 5, it is larger than 0.95 and when x=4, it already become smaller than 0.95. That means we shall order 5 packages right?

Comment: That´s totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

@callculus is correct that you do not have enough information to know
(or even estimate) the Poisson mean $\mu.$ I will use $\mu = 4.5$ for
illustration. Maybe that will give you enough information to make sense
of the problem in your question.

If the average number $X$ of cracks in $4$km of highway is distributed
$\mathsf{Pois}(\mu = 4.5),$ then $\sum_{k=0}^5 \frac{e^{-4.5}4.5^K}{k!} = 0.7029304 < 1.$ I used R to compute this in two ways: (a) by making a vector `pdf` of the six probabilities, and (b) by using the R procedure `dpois`, which is a Poisson PDF. Alternatively, you might use a calculator to sum these six terms.

```
k = 0:5;  pdf = exp(-4.5)*4.5^k/factorial(k)
sum(pdf)
[1] 0.7029304
sum(dpois(k, 4.5))
[1] 0.7029304
```

With $\mu = 4.5$ a graph of the CDF of this Poisson distribution is
as follows.

```
pdf = ppois(k, 4.5)
plot(k, pdf, type="s")  # 's' for 'stairstep'
 points(k, pdf, pch=19)
```

[image]

If you want to be 95% sure to have enough bags of material to
repair all of the cracks in $4$km of this highway, then you
need to find the number $r = 8$ at which the CDF first exceeds $0.95.$
You can use the R quantile function `qpois` (inverse CDF) for that.
Alternatively, using a calculator, you could sum the nine required terms to
verify this result.

```
qpois(.95, 4.5)
[1] 8
ppois(8, 4.5)
[1] 0.9597427
```

Here is an extended CDF plot that goes up to $P(X \le 9)\approx 1.$
The horizontal red line is at $0.95.$

[image]

R code for second figure:

```
k = 0:9;  pdf = ppois(k, 4.5)
plot(k, pdf, type="s")  # 's' for 'stairstep'
points(k, pdf, pch=19)
abline(h=.95, col="red")
```

Comment: Have you noticed the information about the previous exercises in the comments? Based on that information we can deduce that $\mu=2$

Comment: I did not follow that discussion. My goal was not to solve the exact problem, but to give a method of approach.